# Authenticating Users on Mac using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dscl

If I have the following users on my MAC:
test1, test2 and test3

And I am logged into test1. And I would like to enable certain feature for test2 through my application. Hence the user test1 has to authenticate by entering the credentials for test2. Is it possible via cocoa?

I tried dscl command, but i did not find anything useful.

As an example:
When u click enable users in file vault, it shows a tableview with other users on the mac. And then when u click enable, it asks for the user name and password and authenticates the other user.
I am trying ti achieve something similar to this.

Comment: You're looking for Authorization Services. People are most familiar with that API for gaining OS-level privileges, but you can define your own rules and use them just to restrict your own app's behavior. See the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html), specifically references to "self-restricted applications".

Comment: I don't want to restrict just the app behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a way of authenticating any user on the mac. This can be done using `CSIdentity`. The function `CSIdentityAuthenticateUsingPassword` does the needful.